# Fact loading very slow with PyCLIPS, while fast with CLIPS

Tags: python, rule-engine, clips, pyclips

I have a rule-based system with several 100Ks of facts, and I'm getting very poor performance with PyCLIPS just for loading the facts.

I've narrowed it down to a simple example with two templates and a single rule that joins them (and does nothing else):

```
import clips
import timeit

env = clips.Environment()
env.BuildTemplate('F1', '(slot x (type INTEGER))')
env.BuildTemplate('F2', '(slot x (type INTEGER))')
env.BuildRule('Rule1', '(F1 (x ?val)) (F2 (x ?val))', '')

N = 20000
with open('F1.txt', 'w') as f1:
    with open('F2.txt', 'w') as f2:
        for n in xrange(N):
            print >>f1, '(F1 (x {}))'.format(n)
            print >>f2, '(F2 (x {}))'.format(n)

print timeit.timeit(lambda : env.LoadFacts('F1.txt'), number=1)
print timeit.timeit(lambda : env.LoadFacts('F2.txt'), number=1)
```

Output:

```
0.0951321125031
14.6272768974
```

So the second batch of 20K facts takes 14.6 seconds to load. Loading the same fact files from the CLIPS console is instantaneous. Checking different values of `N` reveals that the loading time is roughly proportional to `sqr(N)` (making this completely unusable for large numbers of facts).

Switching the order of operations, and defining the rule after loading the facts does not make things better (obviously the last operation is always the slow one).

Is anyone familiar with this issue? Am I using PyCLIPS in a wrong way?

I am running `PyCLIPS v1.0.7.348` and `CLIPS v6.3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CLIPS 6.3 uses hashing in the joins that compare variables from one pattern to another. This can considerably improve performance when there are a large number of facts and rules similar to the one in your example. In prior versions of CLIPS, when a new F1 fact is asserted, iteration would occur across all F2 facts matching the second pattern (and a similar iteration would occur for each new F2 fact). In version 6.3, iteration occurs only on the facts hashed to the same bucket for the value of ?val. The Readme page on the PyCLIPS website indicates that it's compiled with CLIPS 6.24, so this would explain the difference in performance. Offhand I don't recall any significant API differences between 6.24 and 6.3, so it may be possible to recompile PyCLIPS with the newer version of CLIPS to get the performance improvements.

Comment: With 'CLIPS (V6.24 06/15/06)', the equivalent CLIPS script is also slow at the `(load-facts F2.txt)` step.  So, yes, the issue is with the CLIPS version, not the PY interface.

Comment: Is there a source for CLIPS 6.3 that's readily compiled on Linux (debian/Ubuntu)?  I see Windows and Mac installers (and Java and Android ports).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, PyCLIPS does not compile readily with CLIPS 6.30 due to several API changes. I will try to work it out.

Comment: Here is a [PyCLIPS patch](https://sourceforge.net/p/pyclips/feature-requests/21/) that supports compilation with CLIPS 6.3.